# Alfresco: check java backend is group empty

Tags: java, alfresco

I Need to check if the group is empty. 
First checks is group exist, follow or is empty.

My version is **Alfresco 4.2.c Community**

```
if(authorityService.authorityExists(group_name)){
    //TODO check group is empty 
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Is there any way to check whether the group is empty?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, try

```
public Set<String> getContainedAuthorities(AuthorityType type, String name, boolean immediate);
```

from `AuthorityService`.

```
if (authorityService.getContainedAuthorities(AuthorityType.USER, groupName, false).isEmpty()) {
// No users in group or nested group
}
```